# Cyberpunk 2077 cloud sync conflict on launch

Tags: cyberpunk-2077, epic-games-launcher

I've been playing Cyberpunk 2077 for a few days now - I purchased it in the Epic Game Store.

So far, whenever I launch the game from the Epic app, I get this message *each and every time*:

[image]

I generally don't shut down my computer or quit the Epic Store app immediately after playing.

What does it indicate? That my internet connection bandwidth is not enough to upload the save file to the cloud after I quit the game? Was the upload interrupted? How can I force it to upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register an account in the REDlauncher application as well and then the cloud sync is visible on the savegames so the conflict is no longer there.

[image]